# Can not type text in textview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview

I have an  editable textview to enter some description . when i click on the textview the keyboard appears. My problem is when i try to enter some text via keyboard it is not coming in the textview. Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Code, please.  We need something to work with, because only 2 of us are psychic, and they're asleep.

Comment: Set your textview behaviour Editable.if you have use textview with xib then Click on your textview in xib. Go to attribute inspecter and you will able to set the behavior. or if you have set textview programmatically then write this code "textView.userInteractionEnabled = Yes;" and Your "textview.editable = YES;"

Comment: please post your code also ...!!

Comment: @femina textview is editable that is why the keyboard appears..:)

Comment: @Melbourne what happens if you only return YES in `-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not return NO in ...

`-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text`

otherwise it will not allow you to add text.

Edit:
From `TextView` reference:

> textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText: Asks the delegate
> whether the specified text should be replaced in the text view.
>
> (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString
> *)text
>
> Parameters:
>
> textView: The text view containing the changes.
>
> range: The current selection range. If the length of the range is 0, range
> reflects the current insertion point. If the user presses the Delete
> key, the length of the range is 1 and an empty string object replaces
> that single character.
>
> text: The text to insert.
>
> Return Value: YES if
> the old text should be replaced by the new text; NO if the replacement
> operation should be aborted.

Answer (score 2):

You must return YES in this delegate method, else no text whatsoever will be allowed in fields that you are the delegate of, like so:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [m_CtrlTxtViewDescription resignFirstResponder];
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
        return NO;
    }    
    return YES;
}
```

`shouldChangeTextInRange...`, as the name suggests, is the method that the text view calls when text is added through the keyboard.  Delegates are asked whether or not text should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. It Happens with me also. But No worry we can't able to enter text in text via my pc's Keyboard, but when you declare.

```
self.yourtextview.userInteractionenabled = YES;

self.yourtextview.editable = Yes;
```

Then you can enter text via using device or simulators keyboard.It will work perfectly.